# I want to remove fake experience from resume

Tags: ethics, work-experience

I have a total of five years experience currently reflecting on my resume. Two years original experience, a year of fake experience and two years from where I'm currently working. I've recently realized my mistake and the ethical dilemma of it all and I would like to remove fake experience.

Unfortunately my current company has highlighted this fake experience on an offer letter. If my next company were to ask about this previously shown experience that has now been removed, then what will happen.

Comment: This isn't really a duplicate; in the linked duplicate the employer added the fake entries.

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:** Come clean.  Immediately.

If you told a lie about where you worked, it *will* be found out, so well done for at least realising this and trying to correct your mistake.  However, I think at this stage that it's too late but to do anything but come completely clean.  If you lied on your CV and that got you a job, then you got the job under fraudulent circumstances.  Tell the truth, correct your CV and hope they do not withdraw the offer.

I know you don't want to hear this, but I think it's very likely they will withdraw based on the falsehood in your CV.  Chalk it up as a costly exercise in professionalism and make sure you are totally honest on your CV from this point on.

Comment: Legally I have no idea, you will need to talk to a lawyer about that.  Professionally it's highly likely you have damaged your reputation with this company, but probably less than if you were found out instead of admitting your deceipt..

Comment: thank you for your suggestion. I will move ahead with honesty.